# Edit CSS to apply for certain elements

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I know it's a dumb question but I couldn't find a solution myself. I have two lists in my HTML page. First one is :

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href='@Url.Action("MainPage","Shirts")'>Main Page</a></li>
  <li><a href='@Url.Action("OnSale","Shirts")'>On Sale</a></li>
  <li><a href='@Url.Action("Recent","Shirts")'>Recent</a></li>
</ul>
```

The second one is a PagedListPager which generates an HTML list :

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Mainpage",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

This is my CSS for this HTML :

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;

}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}

li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}


li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

My problem is that, I want my CSS to work for only the first list, not the second one. I know I need to add a class for first list's elements and edit CSS for that class. But I couldn't do it. I don't know what to do for `li ul li a`  in CSS. Can you tell me how to edit CSS and first list in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Post the generated HTML for the second list.

Comment: @ManojKumar why do you need it? I want CSS to work for 1st list.

Comment: I am really not sure what is the structure of the second list.

Comment: @ManojKumar The CSS I posted is supposed to work for first list. I guess we shouldn't do anything for second list.

Comment: @jason: You have an id `menu` on the first list. Id should be unique, so I am assuming that your second list will not have the same id. With this knowledge, you could simply use the id selector for your CSS. `ul#menu...` Here is a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3tmhnnwb/ (When you are at it, you should remove `float:left` from your `li` because it already is `display: inline-block;`

Comment: As @Abhitalks said, that's why I need to check the structure of second list to avoid any styles being written to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#menu > li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 child selectors to select specific properties:

```
ul li a { /* shared styles */ }
ul > li > a { /* parent list styles */ }
ul ul > li > a { /* child list styles */ }
```

https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You say you have two lists on your page (so two `ul` elements). And you only want to apply certain css to the first list without using a class or id selector.

You can use the `first-of-type` pseudo selector, like so:

```css
ul:first-of-type {  }
```

And to apply the css to its children:

```css
ul:first-of-type li {  }
```

According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type) this is pretty well supported (unless you need IE8 support).